# Dynamically populated spinner is not returning a view and I am unable to select items

Tags: android, spinner, adapter

This is the Select.java file that populates the spinners

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class select extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_select);
    final Spinner s1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.s1);
    ArrayAdapter s1adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.s1,R.layout.spin);
    s1adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spin);
    s1.setAdapter(s1adapter);
    final ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<>();
    s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            array.add("1");
            long iid = parent.getSelectedItemId();
            if (iid == 0) {
                array.clear();
                array.add("id 1");
            } else if (iid == 1) {
                array.clear();
                array.add("id 2");
                array.add("id 3");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
    Spinner s2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.s2);
    Adapter s2adapter = new Adapter(this,R.layout.spin,array);
    s2.setAdapter(s2adapter);
    final String l = null;
    s2.setSelection(0);
    s2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent less = new Intent(getBaseContext(),less.class);

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"in",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            if (parent.getItemAtPosition(position).equals("id 1")) {
                less.putExtra("lesson_1", l);
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"in",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            } else if (parent.getItemAtPosition(position).equals("id 2")) {
                less.putExtra("lesson_2", l);
            } else if (parent.getItemAtPosition(position).equals("id 3")) {
                less.putExtra("lesson_3", l);
            }
            startActivity(less);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
        }
```

}
           The following is spin.xml the custom view for spinner

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/testing"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:gravity="top"
 android:singleLine="true"
 android:textSize="20sp"
 android:typeface="sans"
 android:textStyle="bold"
 android:textColor="@android:color/white"
 android:background="@android:color/black"/>
```

The following is the adapter to inflate the view in the spinner

```
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.text.Layout;
 import android.view.LayoutInflater;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;
 import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
 import android.widget.TextView;

 import java.util.ArrayList;


 public class Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
 Context c;
 ArrayList<String> list;
 public Adapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<String> list) {
    super(context,R.layout.spin, list);
    this.c=context;
    this.list=list;
 }

 @Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(convertView==null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inf =(LayoutInflater)           c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView=inf.inflate(R.layout.spin,null);}
    TextView a =(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.testing);
    a.setText(list.get(position));
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(convertView==null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inf =(LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView=inf.inflate(R.layout.spin,null);}
    TextView a =(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.testing);
    a.setText(list.get(position));
    return convertView;
}
```

}

The spinner doesn't show any items initially but does on click. Items are not getting selected. Proof is the makeToast isn't working.
Kindly suggest something.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
allusers.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // clicked item will be shown as spinner
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
});
```

Refer here:-
http://coderzpassion.com/android-spinner-get-data-from-sqlite-database/

Comment: I think the problem lies in the getview method in the adapter